# Exclusion paths on a UILabel's TextContainer

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, textkit

Is it possible to set exclusion paths on a UILabel? The apple documentation states that UILabel is now built upon TextKit but a UILabel does not seem to expose a textContainer property.

I am looking to implement a tableview cell which includes multiple labels and a roux badge which the labels should not overlap (shown below).

[image]

If it is not possible with a UILabel how can I make a TextView act like a UILabel (no scroll, selection etc) and size it to fit it's contents?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is correct that UILabel does not expose the TextKit stack, so you can't set an exclusion path.

However, you don't really *need* UILabel; it is easy to draw directly with TextKit into a rectangular graphics context, and now you *can* set an exclusion path (because you are drawing with TextKit). To draw with TextKit, just build the text kit "stack", customizing in any way you like, and then, when it's time to draw, call the layout manager's `drawBackgroundForGlyphRange:...` and `drawGlyphsForGlyphRange:...`.

Comment: Here's an example where I draw directly into a graphics context (in a UIView subclass's `drawRect:` with TextKit: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch10p543drawingWithTextKit/ch23p815attributedStringDrawing3/StyledText.m

Comment: If I went this route would I have to calculate the height of the cell manually in HeightForRow? Currently I use systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize similar to this http://blog.jldagon.me/blog/2013/12/07/auto-layout-and-uitableview-cells/

Comment: Yes, the layout manager tells you the height too. It does everything!

Comment: thanks for the help. Is it possible to set a minimum fontSize/Scale and a maximum number of lines this way?

Comment: @matt Your example is a 404 :(

Comment: @Nathanial that was March of 2014. I'm sure you can find the example if you think about it.

Comment: @Nathaniel https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch10p543drawingWithTextKit/ch23p815attributedStringDrawing3/StyledText.swift would appear to be an updated version.